# Selective exposure of methods and variables of one class to another in Python | (interfaces?)

Tags: python, oop, interface

I am trying to create a simulation of a simple robot which moves about in a 2-D world using pygame. There are obstacles in the world. The robot only has contact sensors. So it can only sense something if it collides either with the boundaries of the world or the obstacles in it. So, collision detection is of utmost importance here.

I have two principal classes World and Robot. The World class contains information about the geometry of the world and also contains a list of Obstacles. The Robot class contains information about the Geometry of the robot and it's current position in the world. I believe, (but I am not sure ) that Robot should be contained in the World class since it is a part of the world. The  Robot has methods to display itself and move which changes its position in the world. But for collision detection, I need information about the World such as its boundaries and the list of obstacles.

Now, I could make work my simple simulation by making the World class instance a member of the Robot class. This way, my robot gets information about the world and I happily do the collision detection. But, this doesn't make me happy.

Because, I might want to extend the simulation by having other robots in the world and things in the world which I don't want to expose to the robot (I am just experimenting with various AI algorithms here). In future, I might want to try out something wherein the robot has 0 knowledge of the world and it gains knowledge by exploring it.

If this were Java, I would have created an interface (say RobotWorldKnowledge) which the World class would implement and pass this to the Robot class. This interface would have selective knowledge of the world which the robot would use.

I don't know how to do this in python. I tried Googling "interfaces in python" but couldn't find a proper example. Most answers tell that interfaces are not necessary in python.

I might be wrong in what I assumed. Please help me out.

Thanks in advance

shahensha

Comment: An interface in Java is part of the static typing system.  It tells the compiler that a class implements certain methods.  Python has no static type system so there is not Python equivalent of a Java interface.

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: Stack Overflow question checklist

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are good interface frameworks in Python - 
but it also allwos one to create a quick and dirty thing - 
like an object proxy that would only expose the desired methods and attributes of an underlying object.

This can be done simply writting a proper `__getattribute__` method in a class:

```
class Interface(object):
    def __init__(self, real_object, interface):
        if isinstance(interface, str):
            interface = interface.split()
        self.interface  = interface
        self.object = real_object
        Interface.validate(self)

    def __getattribute__(self, attr):
        # Retrieve the real attributes of self,
        # bypassing the normal attribute mechanism:
        interface = object.__getattribute__(self, "interface")
        real_object =  object.__getattribute__(self, "object")
        if attr in interface:
            return getattr(real_object, attr)
        raise AttributeError

    def validate(self):
        interface = object.__getattribute__(self, "interface")
        real_object =  object.__getattribute__(self, "object")
        for attr in interface:
            try:
                getattr(real_object, attr)
            except AttributeError:
                raise ValueError("Passed object does not conform to given interface")
```

And:

```
>>> class A(object):
...   a = 1 
...   b = 2
...   c = 3
... 
>>> a = A()
>>> b = Interface(a, "a b")
>>> b = Interface(a, "a b")>>> b.a
1
>>> b.b
2
>>> b.c
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 16, in __getattribute__
AttributeError
>> class C(object): pass
... 
>>> Interface(C(), "a")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 7, in __init__
  File "<stdin>", line 25, in validate
ValueError: Passed object does not conform to given interface
```

Answer (score 1):

Python doesn't have interfaces. Maybe you could use the [`abc`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/abc.html) module to write an Abstract Base Class and let all the objects in your world implement the abstract methods.

For example you could have:

```
import abc

class RobotWorldKnowledge(object):
    __metaclass__ = abc.ABCMeta

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def get_information(self, *args):
        pass

    ...


class Robot(RobotWorldKnowledge):
    def get_information(self, *args):
       ...

class World(RobotWorldKnowledge):
    def get_information(self, *args):
        ...
```

Alternatively you simply state that when in your documentation you mention a `RobotWorldKnowledge` item you mean an object implementing a `X` method with a certain signature that should return information in a certain way... so you define the interface in the documentation and leave all the rest to duck-typing.

This is a common solution(see things like file-like object which is often used in the standard library).